# How to require many to many relation with code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework with Code First to create a database and so on.

```
public class Company : Entity // Entity contains an ID and a RowVersion
{
    // some Properties
    //
    public virtual ICollection<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
}

// No Attributes here, because this Model has to be reusable
public class Profile : Entity
{
    // some Properties
    //
    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to require a Company to have a Profile (cn:n), that manages that Company. I've got some "Business Logic" that takes care of editing the entities, mainly because of the validation part. That Logic would validate if the required relations are set anyways. I've got two Questions here:

Should the DB have the relations optional (for editing conveniance)? The "Business Logic" would have to be the only one editing the DB.

Or else how would i set the relation required?

---

I wouldn't mind if you go a bit of course, there is far too few about many to many relations with EF on the internet, in my opinion. (I'm new here, so never mind if this goes against some rule)

---

**EDIT**
I'm aware of the way with the 3rd table, but that is my point: [How to require many to many relation with code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034357/how-to-require-many-to-many-relation-with-code-first?noredirect=1#comment46310537_29034357)

Comment: Have you thought about creating a third entity that handle that n:n relationship?

Comment: @Guillelon Yes i have, that would have been the emergency option. But the point of code first is that you don't have to care about how the DB does it, you are only concerned about the Classes. And in that manner, a third class (plus 3 other relation classes, i've got many many to many relations) without any other Properties would not be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn your entity into a validatable object by implementing the `IValidatableObject` interface, with a method that will check that you always have at least 1 item in the collection. The method is called by EF when you call `SaveChanges()`

```
public class Company : Entity, IValidatableObject
{
    public virtual ICollection<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) 
    { 
        if (!Profiles.Any()) 
           yield return new ValidationResult("Company must have at least 1 Profile"); 
    }
}

public class Profile : Entity, IValidatableObject
{
    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) 
    { 
        if (!Companies.Any()) 
           yield return new ValidationResult("Profile must have at least 1 Company"); 
    }
}
```

Reference: [IValidateableObject example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/gg193959#IValidatableObject)

Answer (score 3):

When designing a database when this situation arises (many to many) use an additional table to separate this regard. For example, we have two tables t1 and t2 with t1 many to many to t2, create a table t3 that is relevant:
t1 one-to-many to t3 and t2 one-to-many t3.

In your situation, you need to create an additional class, like this:

```
public class CompanyProfile {
  public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
}
```

In your classees Company and Profile create the link to CompanyProfile class.

Comment: You're right, but also [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034357/how-to-require-many-to-many-relation-with-code-first?noredirect=1#comment46310537_29034357). --> Edit in the Question

Comment: @LukasDörig ok, I'm usually use this way to resolve my task. I'm not sure, but maybe this can help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#ManyToMany

Comment: @netwer why a list of elements? and not ElementId?

Comment: @netwer I already found this page today, sadly didn't help. Thanks for the effort :D

Comment: @adricadar, in my answer I showed only example for understand. yes, you're right this can be ElementId, I think, why not.

Comment: @LukasDörig ok, you are welcome
Sorry, I don't know any ways to resolve your task. :(